# Route.push doesn't work correctly in the second try

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I have a webpage with vue and I use vuetable to show some information. The user click on the row and then change the page to show more detail.

In vuetable function onRowClick I have

```
onRowClick({data}, field) {
   let userId = data.id
   this.$router.push({
     name: 'user',
     params: {user_id: userId}
   })
}
```

In the page of the user I have a button to go back

```
v-bind:to="{name: 'users-list'}
```

But when I want to pick another user vue throws and error

```
[vue-router] missing param for named route "user": Expected "user_id" to be defined
```

I don't understand why in the first try works but in the second it doesn't. I print the id in the function onRowClick and always show the id, but in the second try, in the route, show undefined

Comment: Can you show the code that sets your user ID, and anything that might affect it?

Comment: You mean the onRowClick function? My api service
`getUser: userId=> {
    return ApiService.query(`users/${userId}`)
  },`

Comment: Is there a reason why it's `let userId` camelCased, but in the params it's `user_id` snake_cased? Just a typo here?

Comment: No, that was my mistake, I edited to avoid confutions.